# Cross-region copy fails for Linode Object Storage

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, linode, botocore

We're using `boto3` with Linode Object Storage, which is compatible with AWS S3 according to their documentation.
Everything seems to work well, except cross-region copy operation.
When I download an object from source region/bucket and then upload it to destination region/bucket, everything works well. Although, I'd like to avoid that unnecessary upload/download step.

I have the bucket named `test-bucket` on both regions. And I'd like to copy the object named `test-object` from `us-east-1` to `us-southeast-1` cluster.

Here is the example code I'm using:

```py
from boto3 import client
from boto3.session import Session

sess = Session(
    aws_access_key_id='***',
    aws_secret_access_key='***'
)

s3_client_src = sess.client(
    service_name='s3',  
    region_name='us-east-1',
    endpoint_url='https://us-east-1.linodeobjects.com'
)
# test-bucket and test-object are already exists.

s3_client_trg = sess.client(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='us-southeast-1',
    endpoint_url='https://us-southeast-1.linodeobjects.com'
)

copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'test-bucket',
    'Key': 'test-object'
}
s3_client_trg.copy(CopySource=copy_source, Bucket='test-bucket', Key='test-object', SourceClient=s3_client_src)
```

When I call:

```py
s3_client_src.list_objects(Bucket='test-bucket')['Contents']
```

It shows me that the `test-object` exists, But when I run copy, then it throws following message:

`An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the CopyObject operation: Unknown`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that `test-object` is actually present in the `test-bucket`?

Comment: Yes, it's for sure. `list_objects` also lists it.